# Not sure if left join or a inner join is best for this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
SELECT a.RegPropertyid,a.Bndnbr,a.account_balance,
       abs(a.account_balance) as BondBalance,b.BndregDate
INTO Jan2014ValidFin
FROM Jan2014Valid a 
LEFT JOIN  BNDtable b on a.RegPropertyid=b.propid and a.Bndnbr=b.Bndnbr
Where a.RegPropertyid is not null

 select Bnd_regDate from BND_table  
 Where Prop_id in (select regpropertyid from Jan2014ValidFin where 
 regpropertyid is not null) and BndregDate  is not null
```

Comment: You have two queries.  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: What does "best" mean? They *might* return different data, but they might return *the same* data. Depends on the relationship. Do either versions of the query give you the data you need? How can *we* know that?

Comment: @Mzila You need to have more information in your question

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN takes all the records from the first table mentioned and the records that the second mentioned table has is common with the first.

INNER JOIN only takes the common terms from both.

If TableA was A,B,C,F,G and TableB was C,D,E,

`TableA LEFT JOIN TableB` would give you A,B,C,F,G

`TableA INNER JOIN TableB` would give you C

Comment: i am not sure if it's the joins type thats the problem. i am worried as to why would the data not pull up from the other table when they match of propid and bndnbr .

Comment: which columns in which table aren't pulling the null values?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need. A left join on the first select will get you all the rows from Jan2014Valid and any matching rows from BNDtable if the propertyid column matches propid and bndnbr matches bndnbr. If it does not match you still get the row from Jan2014Valid and nulls for the columns from BNDtable.

If you make it a right join you get all the rows from BNDtable and and any matching data (columns) from Jan2014Valid table.

Comment: so i am saying the records considered as null actually exist in the source table , when i use any of the joins it's excludes the null but when i go and check those nulls from the source table Bndtable the data is there. i am concern as to why it's not picking up. what is it that missing that i am not doing cause the conditions stands

Answer (score 0):

The Null Results that you're mentioning above aren't showing up because you wrote "is not Null", delete that and you should be good

Comment: when i do this , the bndregdate null increase as it's add more nulls. :(